# How to set CPU Affinity for android tasks

Tags: processes

I have a dual core android device.
Is there any way to set CPU Affinity for android tasks ?

Answer (score 1):

No, I suspect that there isn't any app that can do the job. You could write it yourself, it shouldn't be too hard. It seems that the best way to do it is using the [NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467848/is-it-possible-to-set-affinity-with-sched-setaffinity-in-android) but it should be possible even in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238272/java-thread-affinity).

Comment: And the Java method uses JNI, so even Java needs to get help from the native side of things.